# net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

Tags: authorization, oauth, linkedin-api

```ruby
@@timestamp = nil

def generate_oauth_url
  @@timestamp = timestamp
  url = CONNECT_URL + REQUEST_TOKEN_PATH + "&oauth_callback=#{OAUTH_CALLBACK}&oauth_consumer_key=#{OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY}&oauth_nonce=#{NONCE}    &oauth_signature_method=#{OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD}&oauth_timestamp=#{@@timestamp}&oauth_version=#{OAUTH_VERSION}"
  puts url
  url             
end

def sign(url)
  Base64.encode64(HMAC::SHA1.digest((NONCE + url), OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET)).strip
end

def get_request_token
  url = generate_oauth_url
  signed_url = sign(url)          
  request = Net::HTTP.new((CONNECT_URL + REQUEST_TOKEN_PATH),80)
  puts request.inspect
  headers = { "Authorization" => "Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce = #{NONCE}, oauth_callback = #{OAUTH_CALLBACK}, oauth_signature_meth    od = #{OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD}, oauth_timestamp=#{@@timestamp}, oauth_consumer_key = #{OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY}, oauth_signature = #{signed_url}, oauth_versio    n = #{OAUTH_VERSION}" }

  request.post(url, nil,headers)                  
end

def timestamp
  Time.now.to_i
end
```

I am trying to do what oauth does in an attempt to understand how to use the Authorization headers. I am also getting the following error. I am trying to connect to the linkedin API.

`/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in 'initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)`

I would really appreciate it if someone could nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Name or service not known" is a socket-level error which usually points to either an invalid IP address/DNS hostname, or an unregistered port name (e.g. `telnet the.host.name service` where `service` is not a registered service name.)

Check that `CONNECT_URL` holds a valid URL.

**EDIT:**  I'm not a Ruby programmer, but I wouldn't mind betting that `Net::HTTP.new` requires a hostname (e.g. www.facebook.com) as the first argument, not a complete URL (e.g. www.facebook.com/login.php?method=oauth).

Answer (score 9):

You also get this error when you have no internet connection since a DNS lookup is often the first thing that happens when establishing a TCP connection using a hostname.

Unplug your network cable and try:

```
Socket.getaddrinfo("www.example.com", "http")
# => SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: I'm getting this error from my server when I try using git with GitLab. The message gets outputted in my terminal through ssh. The error was there Twp days ago, and now it's gone. Maybe my linode host was experiencing DNS trouble?

Comment: This worked, I turned my `wifi` and turned `on` and voila Its done