# Cannot git clone or push from/to gitlab server

Tags: clone, repository, gitlab

I have now built up a gitlab server on my Ubuntu computer as your installation guide on [www.gitlab.org](http://www.gitlab.org) official website tells.
Then I signed in the gitlab server homepage through IE browser in the client computer.

Subsequently I modified the "My Profile" and uploaded my SSH public key.
Logged out and reboot server, then login again.
Create my first git project : `gitlab_testing.git`

At that time when I did '`git clone`' to download the `gitlab_testing.git` repository from server,   or when I push the first commit upon to server,  it always showed the below error message, please kindly see the below snapshots :

[image: failed push]

[image: failed clone]

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608331/net-http-rb560in-initialize-getaddrinfo-name-or-service-not-known-sockete):

> "`Name or service not known`" is a socket-level error which usually points to either an invalid IP address/DNS hostname, or an unregistered port name.

Check if this is a proxy issue (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459006/with-nokogiri-i-am-getting-error-initialize-getaddrinfo-no-such-host-is-know)).

Either you need to configure a proxy, or make sure that you *don't* use a proxy when accessing a local gitlab server (using the **`no_proxy`** environment variable)