# Sending POST request with HTTP headers

Tags: ruby, api, rest

quite new to this been learning about API's in Ruby. Using an Emails service's API to create a user in a system.

This is an example of the POST:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/core/postgres-pages-xy/api/rest/v4/user/create?email=user003@test.invalid HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic bWFzdGVyQGVuubXVjLmVjaXJjbGUuZGU6aDhuc3d1cnN0
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: localhost:8080
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json
Content-Length: 86

[{"name":"user.FirstName","value":"Stan"}, {"name":"user.LastName", "value":"Laurel"}]
```

I think I am close(ish)? in Ruby was hoping someone would tell me how I send my authentication through. System requires login headers not sure how to do that, will be an email and a password:

```
    require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("https://site.com/api/rest/v4/user/create?email=ruby1@ruby.com")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)


request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
request.basic_auth 'email', 'pass'

request["user.FirstName"] = 'Liam'
request["user.LastName"] = 'Coates'

response = https.request(request)
puts response
```

Thanks for feedback or learnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter the credentials in the URL:

```
url = "http://username:password@localhost:8080/core/postgres-pages-xy/api/rest/v4/user/create"
```

If the username and password are there, it should automatically do HTTP basic auth ([source](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post_form)).

However supposedly this is deprecated, so there is a longer solution:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

Comment: I've used that now and updated my code to the above - I'll have to work on it because I don't know what these errors are: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:564:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:564:in `open'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:564:in `connect'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:48:in `timeout'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:564:in `connect'

Comment: @Liam, the getaddrinfo error occurs essentially when your script is not able to connect to the internet. Are you running behind a proxy? Also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608331/net-http-rb560in-initialize-getaddrinfo-name-or-service-not-known-sockete

Comment: Through a work network I assume it is a proxy - I'll have a go at home I guess.